# Unit testing method that interacts with Build.TAGS

Tags: android, junit

Is it possible through the use of Mockito or Reflection to unit test a method that interacts with `android.os.Build.TAGS`?

I'd prefer to be able to dictate what value is returned by `Build.TAGS`.